# how to find control in usercontrol from same usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a user control that it have some control like textbox i want find all of textbox of usercontrol and if it had spacial content repleace this content with an other . i wrote following code in aspx form and it worked correctly but when i wrote same code in usercontrol and i used "this" keyword insted of "form1"  coldnot get right result

```
 public void clearTextBox()
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textBox = ctl as TextBox;
                if (textBox.Text == "&nbsp;")
                { textBox.Text = ""; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of your .ascx usercontrol?

Comment: its very larg.but iam using update panel in usercontrol.

Comment: Instead of `form1`, use the `parent container` of the `TextBox`.

Comment: exactly its my problem,cuz i dont know what is the parent of textbox

Comment: You can find it by `TextBoxID.NamingContainer` or `TextBoxID.Page` or `TextBoxID.Parent`

Comment: thanks alot .i used TextBoxID.Parent and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Control` object to method `clearTextBox` and use its `ControlCollection` to get each child control.

```
public void clearTextBox(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = ctl as TextBox;
            if (textBox.Text == "&nbsp;")
            { textBox.Text = ""; }
        }
    }
}
```